# $.93 * 600 = 558$ = point range $558-600$ for A. what is the formula to insert for automatic calculation

Tags: statistics

I'm probably not using the right terminology but I'm trying to find the formula to insert into Numbers for generating a point range. The course has 600 points. I know the percents that will be used to convert to letter grade. For example $93%$ to $100%$ is an A. Now what is the formula to insert to calculate what the point range would be to receive an A etc.? I know that .$93 * 600 = 558$. So that point range is $558-600$ to receive an A but what is the formula to insert for automatic calculation so I don't waste more minutes! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by an "automatic" calculator? If you have a graphing calculator, you could probably write a program to do what you're asking, but I don't think that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every 600-558+1 = 43 points jumped a grade, A=3, B=2, C=1

$$\lfloor {x-429 \over 43} \rfloor$$